# OpenSSL API: CRL checking doesnt work me

Tags: security, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to add to my X509_store, CRLs management.
I did that:

```
int x509_add_crl_to_store( X509_STORE * store, const char * crl_file ){
STACK_OF(X509_CRL) *crls = 0;
X509_CRL *x;

CHK(!store, SSL_FAIL);

if (X509_STORE_set_default_paths(store) != 1){
    MITM_PRINT_ERR("Error loading the system-wide CA certificates");
    return SSL_FAIL;
}

if(load_crls_from_PEM(crl_file, &crls) != 1)
{
    MITM_PRINT_ERR("load_crls_from_PEM failed.");
    return SSL_FAIL;
}

while((x=sk_X509_CRL_pop(crls)) != 0){
    if(X509_STORE_add_crl(store,x) != 1){
        MITM_PRINT_ERR("Failed to add CRL to store.");
        return SSL_FAIL;
    }
    else{
        MITM_PRINT_ERR("Succedded to add CRL to store.");
    }
}

/* set the flags of the store so that CRLs are consulted */
//X509_STORE_set_flags(store, X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK | X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK_ALL| X509_V_FLAG_TRUSTED_FIRST);

return SSL_OK; }
```

The issue is:

- If I enable the last lines:

  X509_STORE_set_flags(store, X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK | X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK_ALL);

so the CRL checking is working BUT the trusted store is not checked anymore.

And of course, if I disable those lines, the trusted CA checking is working but not the CRLs.

Any idea ???

Thanks
Mikael

Comment: When you say "trusted store is not checked anymore" do you mean the untrusted CAs are checked first or do you mean the certificate chaining process entirely fails?

Comment: I mean the root certificate is no more recognized as trusted (and it appears in the store). I don't know exactly if the verification failed or the trusted store is not checked at all .... because it is done internally by openSSL. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One should be very careful while enabling the CRL flag `X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK_ALL` in combination with `X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK`, because the combined effect of both is to *require* the presence of **every** CRL corresponding to all the CAs in the chain of trust. So if you added the CA cert `Verisign.pem` to your trust store, and it is part of the chain of trust, you **must** add the CRL `Verisign_CRL.pem`.

In your particular case, you have added all the certs in `/etc/ssl/certs` directory using `X509_STORE_set_default_paths(store)`. To get verification to work correctly, you need to add a CRL corresponding to every CA in that directory which you expect to be part of the chain.

A better method would be to narrow down your list of CAs to those for which you have CRLs, and add them individually using `X509_STORE_add_cert(store, ca_cert)`.